# C++ memory in dynamic array after delete

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

[image]. Following photo describes memory before delete and after delete. I am wondering why I still see some kind of memory address. My question is: Is it caused by compilator or I did something wrong during freeing the memory.

Code snippet:

```
__int16** Matrix{};
size_t width{ 35 };
size_t height{ 4 };
Matrix = new __int16* [height];
for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    Matrix[i] = new __int16[width];
    for (size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        Matrix[i][j] = NULL;
    }
};
//DEALLOCATE ALLOCATED MEMORY
for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    delete[] Matrix[i];
}
delete[] Matrix;
```

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. Just don't expect any behavior reliant on content after `delete`ing those allocations. Referencing said-memory after returning it to the memory management system invokes *undefined behavior*. The memory manager is freely able to use that memory for other requests, which you can probably witness if you expand your example to do so.

Comment: well, the only thing you did wrong is to use `new` and `delete` when you can find a lot of containers (the most basic one being `std::vector`) that does the allocation / deallocation for you. for instance, creating a `std::vector<std::vector<__int16>>` object defines a matrix rather easily.

Comment: Since C++11 there are standardized names for fixed-width integers with `#include<cstdint>`, e.g. `std::int16_t`. I would suggest using those instead of unportable `__int16`. Similarly since C++11, there is `nullptr` which should always be preferred over `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks guys a lot for your replies. I wanted to be sure, Now I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deallocating memory that a pointer points to does neither cause the pointer to be set to null, nor does it cause the memory that is deallocated to be zeroed.

Deallocation only means that you tell the (system) allocator that you don't use that memory anymore and that it can use it for other allocation requests. The allocator does not need to modify the memory in any way.

Dereferencing a pointer that points to memory which you deallocated by a call to `delete[]` causes undefined behavior. This does not mean that you will observe any particular behavior, it means that anything could happen. It could e.g. happen that the `delete` has no effect on your program's memory, but that still doesn't allow you to keep using it.